# python, storing dictionaries inside a dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, pandas

I've built a pandas dataframe which is storing a simple dictionary in each cell. For example:

```
{'Sales':0,'Revenue':0}
```

I can retrieve a specific value from the dataframe via:

```
df[columnA][index100]['Revenue']
```

But now I'd like to plot a graph of all the Revenue values from the dictionaries in `columnA` - what is the best way of achieving this?

Would life be easier in the long run if I dropped the dictionaries and instead used two identically sized dataframes?  (Am very new to pandas so not sure of best practice).

Comment: Update:  In the end I went with a hierarchical index which continues to function perfectly - thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way to get all the Revenue values from a column A is `df[columnA].map(lambda v: v['Revenue'])`.

Depending on what you're doing, life may indeed be easier if you tweak your structure a bit.  For instance, you could use a hierarchical index with "Sales" and "Revenue" as the keys in one level.

Answer (score 4):

For the majority of use cases you it's not a good idea to be storing dictionaries in DataFrame.
Another datastructure worth mentioning is a [Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).

Suppose you have something a DataFrame of dictionaries (with fairly consistent keys):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}], [{'a': 5, 'b': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8}]], columns=list('AB'))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                  A                 B
0  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}  {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
1  {'a': 5, 'b': 6}  {'a': 7, 'b': 8}
```

You can create a Panel (note there are more direct/preferable ways to construct this!):

```
In [13]: wp = pd.Panel({'A': df['A'].apply(pd.Series), 'B': df['B'].apply(pd.Series)})

In [14]: wp
Out[14]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: A to B
Major_axis axis: 0 to 1
Minor_axis axis: a to b
```

Sections of which can be accessed efficiently as DataFrames in a variety of ways, for example:

```
In [15]: wp.A
Out[15]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  5  6

In [16]: wp.minor_xs('a')
Out[16]:
   A  B
0  1  3
1  5  7

In [17]: wp.major_xs(0)
Out[17]:
   A  B
a  1  3
b  2  4
```

So you can do all the pandas DataFrame whizziness:

```
In [18]: wp.A.plot()  # easy!
Out[18]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x1048342d0>
```

*There are also [("experimental") higher dimensional Panels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel4d-experimental).*

Comment: I'll be interested to see what comes out of the N-D experiments.  We have our own homegrown n-dim object we use for data processing, with different kinds of axis, and I often move between flat dataframes and our hypercubes.

Comment: Thanks - I'll experiment with this as well as the hierarchical index mentioned by mentioned previously by @BrenBarn

Comment: @Sylvansight perhaps worth noting from a hierarchical indexed DataFrame you can move to a panel via the to_panel method :)

Comment: @DSM the n-d factories and objects are quite functional ( experimental was a tag from 0.9). Any wish list pls open an issue.

Comment: as of Pandas 0.20.0 panel is deprecated, and per Panda's documentation advice, the way to go is to use a hierarchical index or to transition to xarray as discussed [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/pandas.html#panel-transition)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why it's not a good idea to store dicts in a DataFrame? Is this still relevant (since the thread is quite old)?