# What does this dataframe format mean {'type': 'percentage', 'percentage': 35}?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

This is probably a stupid question but I don't even know how to google this question. I ran this code:

```
import robin_stocks as rs
import pandas as pd

rs.login(username='myUserName',
     password='myPassword',
     expiresIn=86400,
     by_sms=True)

myData1 = rs.orders.get_all_open_stock_orders()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(myData1)

pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 200

print(df1[['trailing_peg']])
```

It returns this:

```
                            trailing_peg
0   {'type': 'percentage', 'percentage': 35}
1   {'type': 'percentage', 'percentage': 55}
2   {'type': 'percentage', 'percentage': 30}
3   {'type': 'percentage', 'percentage': 20}

etc...
```

I simply need the percentages... So I need:

```
35
55
30
20
etc...
```

How do get this data?
What is this format?

```
{'type': 'percentage', 'percentage': 35}
```

I don't understand the colons and curly brackets.

Comment: Provide the output of some of `rs.orders.get_all_open_stock_orders()`. It looks like you're calling the wrong DataFrame constructor given the format of your data.

Comment: But I might just guess `pd.DataFrame(myData1['trailing_peg'])` gets you basically what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I found a solution. I don't understand the mechanics of it but I am posting it in case it is helpful to someone else. Especially since there aren't many examples available involving Robinhood's API.

I went back to "rs.orders.get_all_open_stock_orders()" to post the output per "ALollz" request and discovered that the data is in a similar series of colons and curly brackets. Ultimately I discovered that this format is a dictionary. Evidently, I am working with a pandas dataframe in which each cell is storing a dictionary. This link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510492/python-storing-dictionaries-inside-a-dataframe
```

Has a solution from "BrenBarn" that worked for me:

```
test = df1['trailing_peg'].map(lambda v: v['percentage'])
print(test)
```

Result is:

```
0     35
1     55
2     30
3     20
4     45

etc...
```